# should I be using pipenv in my travis-ci tests? best practices?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, travis-ci, pipenv

I'm getting the following message when running some predefined Pipenv scripts in Travis-CI, and it bring me to the question of; should I be running Pipenv at all in a Travis environment? Does it defeat the purpose of the CI tests?

> Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.

What is the best practice when you use Pipenv for development, and use Travis for CI? Should I be manually running the scripts below that map to `pipenv run unit_test` instead? See below for a section of my `Pipfile`.

`.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
install:
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install --dev
script:
  - pipenv run unit_tests
  - pipenv run linting
  - pipenv run docs
```

`Pipfile`:

```
[scripts]
deploy = "python ./deploy.py"
docs = "python ./docs.py"
linting = "pylint **/*.py"
unit_tests = "python -m pytest --cov=marian tests"
serve = "sh ./serve.sh"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so Travis is using pipenv itself for the virtual env. So, seems awkward beyond installing via `pipenv install --dev`. I dropped all `Pipfile` scripts, and went with the following in `.travis.yml`

```
install:
- pip install pipenv
- pipenv install --dev
script:
- pylint **/*.py
- python -m pytest --cov=marian
- python ./docs.py
```